# Trying to perform an onLoad to render some information but nothing happens

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I've implemented the onLoad function inside of a div that is supposed to render the information once everything is loaded but nothing happens. I know things are a bit different in react so I'm sure it's not as straight forward.

Here is the code for the loadQuestion function:

```
  const loadQuestion = () => {
    dispatch(
      setQuestionInfo({
        questionId: Id,
        questionName: question,
      })
    );
  };
```

Here is the div where the function is loaded. I kept it short for this question:

```
 return (
    <div className="post" onLoad={loadQuestion}>
      <div className="post__info">
        <Avatar src={buildFaastUser.photo} />
        <h5>
          {buildFaastUser.displayName
            ? buildFaastUser.displayName
            : buildFaastUser.email}
        </h5>
        <small>{new Date(timestamp?.toDate()).toLocaleString()}</small>
        <small>{category}</small>
      </div>
      <div className="post__body">
        <div className="post__question">
          <p>{question}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="post__answer">
          {getAnswer.map(({ id, answers }) => (
            <p key={id} style={{ position: "relative", paddingBottom: "20px" }}>
              {Id === answers.questionId ? (
                <span>
                  {parse(answers.answer)}

                </span>
              ) : (
                ""
              )}
            </p>
          ))}
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onLoad` attribute on a div element won't trigger. Plus this isn't the "React way" of doing what you want. If you could use the `onLoad` in this way, it would trigger on every render.

Instead, try using the `useEffect` hook to trigger when the component mounts:

```
useEffect(() => {
  loadQuestion();
}, []);
```